# Change the current selected database

Tags: php, mysqli

Once again thank you for looking at my question.

I am writing a php program, where for the first time I am using multiple databases stored within one mysql server environment.

The first database handles the generic data such as login information and user profiles (including the name of the database that belongs to that profile)

The other databases (as hinted above) are specific to each profile and contain sensitive information, hence keeping them seperate. There is a lot of information in these databases, aprox 12 tables with hundreds and thousands of records in each.

So onto my problem.

I have created about 10 webpages and use php "require_once()" to include pieces that are common to each page such as the database connection. I ensure each page closes the connection after execution.

within this script I created the following function

```
// Function to connect a specific database
    function dbc($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $compDbase){        
        return mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $compDbase) or die ('Error connecting to mysql server, database supplied' . mysqli_error());       
    }
```

the first three variables are static and are set in the same file thats included in all documents requiring the connection. The $compDbase added when called such as here

```
dbc($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, 'database_user1');
```

But this does not seem to work. I have tried adding a mysqli_close($dbc); which is the name of the generic database, before calling the function. I also have tried

```
mysqli_select_db('database_user1', $dbc);
```

to see if I can change the database that is currently selected neither of them work and mysqli doesn't throw any information using mysqli_error();

any hints ?

---

---

**I ANSWERED IT.**

All I need to add was within the query the "database.table"

so first I used the generic database connection $dbc. The code looks like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM database_user1.skill";
```

Comment: Why are you using two or more databases for this? Nobody can see inside your Database (unless you let them), so why storing sensitive data in another database?

Comment: Actually its more for maintenance, The databases are created as people sign up for the service and all the specific information is contain within that database, when they close their account the database is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Hey can you not just simply excute the mysql command : Use db1, use db2?

Comment: Thats a very good suggestion and one I havent tried but should have been the very first thing I tried! I will get back to you

Comment: cannot get this to work in php, i tried sending the first query of use database_user1 and then the query on the table, but it doesn't work. how would you implement this ?

Comment: @Paul-Chambers it is curious to me, does it work when you insert or update something in the current db? do you know where i am going with this?